# How to fetch cell value through user-defined header name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table, like this

```
      | DOG | CAT  | COW  | CHICKEN ...
------+-----+------+------+------
FARM1 |  2  |  0   |   4  |   80
------+-----+------+------+-------
FARM2 |  0  |   3  |   12 | 125
------+-----+------+------+-------
......
```

Is it possible to get the value through the customer headers instead of A2, B2?
I want to be able to fetch the value like so

```
=FARM1DOG
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: If you could be a bit more clear about what you're asking, that would be appreciated.  What immediately comes to mind when reading this is `Indirect()` for calling based on other criteria, but how that is to be applied would be dependent on more information.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: You can use a regular formula with a combination of INDEX/MATCH but you cannot write arbitrary names like "FARM1DOG" (unless you define all the possible combinations)

Comment: Your question is leaving me confused:  "Is it possible to get the value through the customer headers instead of A2, B2?".  I feel that you're asking how to `Index()` based on `Match()`ing criteria indirectly, e.g., I know it's a dog, or I know it's a cat, and I want to know the value for farm 2, we can do that... but i don't know what data you're starting wiht to make any assumptions edgewise, just a small idea about your output.  Maybe you want to start with "2" and see what has 2 items?  It would be umpteen things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing could be done a few ways. I would prefer index(match(...

Assuming your table above is in the top-left corner of the spreadsheet and continues to J10 you could use:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$J$10,MATCH("FARM1",$A$2:$A$10,0),MATCH("DOG",$B$1:$J$1,0))
```

On the other hand, you could do it with named ranges as well, but the names would need to be changed if the column headers changed. Just name each entire column after it's header. So select column B and create a name for the range called "Dog", then the same for all the other columns. Then for the rows name row 2 "Farm1", etc...

Then you can use:

```
=FARM1 DOG
```

(the space between them is the intersect operator)

Comment: There are some index shifts, but I fix it myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Under presumption that your data is small you can also name the Range manually:

1. Select the cell you want to name
2. Formulas -> Define Name [ <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> ]
3. Call it whatever you want

Now you can refer to the cell by the given name:

[image]

---

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could also name the headers only and refer to it via `=OFFSET`.

```
=OFFSET(<VERTICAL NAME>,,COLUMN(<HORIZONTAL NAME>) - COLUMN(<VERTICAL NAME>))
```

In a practical example

```
=OFFSET(farm1,,COLUMN(dog) - COLUMN(farm1))
```

[image]